# Destroying activity and returning to the fragment that called that actvity on clicking on Close button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

My activity consists of many fragments.FeedFragment consists of textviews which when i click opens a new actvity named FeedAnalysis.FeedAnalysis has close,next and previous textview on which onClick event is there.I have problem regarding close textview action.I want when i click on close textview it returns to the FeedFragment.But when i click on close textview it opens a new FeedFragment on top of it.As a result Sliding menu in my fragment doesn't appear.Also when i use back button of mobile, FeedAnalysis activity again appears.I want that my activity is destroyed once i click on close textview and my fragment to be displayed with sliding menu as it was previously.
I am using this code for close button

```
 tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
            tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment newFragment = new FeedFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

Here is my complete code for fragment and activity

FeedFragment

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public FeedFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, FeedAnalysis.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, FeedAnalysis2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView43);

        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, FeedAnalysis3.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search2:

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, FeedSelect.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

FeedAnalysis

```
public class FeedAnalysis extends FragmentActivity {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newsdetails);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment newFragment = new FeedFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), FeedAnalysis2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), FeedAnalysis3.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do finish() on Activity2, it will close Activity2 and all fragments that spawned from Activity2, and therefore it will return to Activity1 (or the fragments that spawned from Activity1).

(The names i used are just as an example)

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should use finish(); method instead of startActivity(i);

Comment: i am not using startActivity(i) for Close textview action..Please  see my code for tv1 in FeedAnalysis.java ..its for "Close" button textview